What is "Snail's Law"?
When Victor and Andrey Pavlovich went to "The Dump" in chapter 21 of Penguin Lost, Andrey told Zhora,

"Remembered her who you were talking to in the sauna? Time - like money for your board, my money, $50 per diem - is short. No sense in wasting it. Infringing Snail's Law is bad enough. Refusing to talk's even worse."

What, exactly, is "snail's law"?

"Snail's Law" is actually the title in original ("Закон улитки"). Are there chapters in your book? It's explained in chapter 8.
Ru text see https://www.litres.ru/book/andrey-kurkov-2/zakon-ulitki-4410605/chitat-onlayn/?page=4

@Andra There are chapter numbers, but no chapter titles. Are there titles in the Russian text?

I just saw that text which is given in the link in the previous comment

As noted by Andra in the comments, Закон улитки ("Snail's law") is the original title of the book (see the cover below) - something which has rather been lost in translation.

The meaning of this phrase essentially underpins the whole narrative. It is briefly explained towards the end of chapter 8, in a speech by Andrey Pavlovich:

“We don’t need much,” Andrey Pavlovich continued, “a bite to eat, a
spot of cash, a roof, and we’re snug as a snail. Which brings us to
Snail’s Law: small snail, small shell, like you; big snail, big shell
like me. Mine, if I outgrow it, I build afresh. No shell — you’re a
slug, and slugs come to a sticky end. Like me to build you one?”

I interpret that as meaning that we must all find a way of protecting ourselves. Without protection we are like a snail without a shell, and anyone in passing can crush you beneath their foot.
Andrey returns to the theme later in chapter 14:

“‘Thou shalt admit to thy home neither stranger, nor semi-stranger,
nor semi-intimate’ — Snail’s Law, Article 3.”

that is, if you let down your defenses, you will be in violation of Snail's law, and you will suffer the consequences.
